# Anybody is able to run langchain gpt4all successfully?

Tags: langchain, gpt4all

The following piece of code is from https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/models/llms/integrations/gpt4all

```
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler


template = """Question: {question}

Answer: Let's think step by step."""

prompt = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question"])

local_path = (
    "./models/ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin"  # replace with your desired local file path
)

# Callbacks support token-wise streaming
callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
# Verbose is required to pass to the callback manager
llm = GPT4All(model=local_path, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=True)
# If you want to use a custom model add the backend parameter
# Check https://docs.gpt4all.io/gpt4all_python.html for supported backends
llm = GPT4All(model=local_path, backend="gptj", callbacks=callbacks, verbose=True)


llm_chain = LLMChain(prompt=prompt, llm=llm)
question = "What NFL team won the Super Bowl in the year Justin Bieber was born?"

llm_chain.run(question)`
```

Here is the error message:

```
Found model file at  ./models/ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin
Invalid model file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 19
     17 callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]
     18 # Verbose is required to pass to the callback manager
---> 19 llm = GPT4All(model=local_path, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=True)
     20 # If you want to use a custom model add the backend parameter
     21 # Check https://docs.gpt4all.io/gpt4all_python.html for supported backends
     22 llm = GPT4All(model=local_path, backend="gptj", callbacks=callbacks, verbose=True)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for GPT4All
__root__
  Unable to instantiate model (type=value_error)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without further info (e.g., versions, OS, ...), it is hard to say what the problem here is.

First thing to check is whether `./models/ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin` is valid. For this, you should compare the checksum of the local file with the valid ones, which you can find here: https://gpt4all.io/models/models.json.

Note that your model is not in the file, and is not officially supported in the current version of gpt4all (1.0.2) anymore, so you might want to download and use `GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin` from their [official website](https://gpt4all.io/index.html). If the checksum is not correct, delete the old file and re-download.

If the problem persists, try to load the model directly via gpt4all to pinpoint if the problem comes from the file / gpt4all package or langchain package.

```py
    from gpt4all import GPT4All

    model = GPT4All("ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin", model_path="./models/")
```

Finally, you are not supposed to call both line 19 and line 22. As the comments state: If you have a predefined model, use 19, if you have a custom one, use line 22.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to installe "ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin" on your pc:

```
from gpt4all import GPT4All
GPT4All(model_name = "ggml-gpt4all-l13b-snoozy.bin")
```

then you can use langchain.llms to access to your model
WARNING : use gpt4all = 0.3.5